# Having a trouble dealing with the object returned from NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios programming and just started learning this last month.

There is one problem that I've been in stuck with for the last two days.
I can't figure out how to fix this problem by myself.

So, I'd like to ask you a favor to help me solve this problem!

This is the error that I'm getting.

```
[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

I learned that I get this error because the object I get from NSUserDefaults is always immutable.

So, I mutableCopy the array that I want to add new object to.

```
    NSMutableArray *temporaryArray = [users[1][@"users"] mutableCopy];
    [temporaryArray addObject:myData];

    users[1][@"users"] = temporaryArray;
```

But, on the third line above, of course, it causes the same error.

I know the reason why it causes this error but I don't know how to code to solve this problem. I think the solution is something very simple and basic, but I can't figure it out how.

I appreciate if anyone helps me to solve this problem!!

Thank you very much in advance!

```
- (void)saveData
{

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *users = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"users"];

    NSDictionary *myData = @{@"name":@"test", @"birthdate":@"1981-01-01", @"sex":@"male"};

    NSMutableArray *temporaryArray = [users[1][@"users"] mutableCopy];
    [temporaryArray addObject:myData];

    users[1][@"users"] = temporaryArray;



    [userDefaults setObject:users forKey:@"users"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    [self.target performSelector:self.action withObject:@"test.png"];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**The structure of "user" Array.**

```
(
    {
    label = "\U81ea\U5206";
    users =         (
                    {
            birthdate = "2013-10-12";
            name = Test;
            sex = "\U7537\U6027";
        }
    );
},
    {
    label = "Family(\U5bb6\U65cf)";
    users =         (
    );
},
    {
    label = "Friends(\U53cb\U9054)";
    users =         (
    );
}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to mutate an immutable dictionary which is one of the objects of the array.

Try the following:

```
- (void)saveData
{

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *users = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"users"] mutableCopy];

    NSDictionary *myData = @{@"name":@"test", @"birthdate":@"1981-01-01", @"sex":@"male"};

    //Create a mutable copy of the dictionary object at index 1.
    NSMutableDictionary* mutableUsers = [users[1] mutableCopy]

    NSMutableArray *temporaryArray = [mutableUsers[@"users"] mutableCopy];
    [temporaryArray addObject:myData];
    mutableUsers[@"users"] = [temporaryArray copy];

    //Replace the dictionary with an immutable copy of the new dictionary.
    users[1] = [mutableUsers copy];

    [userDefaults setObject:users forKey:@"users"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    [self.target performSelector:self.action withObject:@"test.png"];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I take some time to read your code to understand it and I'll try your code soon!

Comment: Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness!! I tried your code now, but I'm getting this error now. "[__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9190560"

Comment: I may have mixed some of the object types. You have not given any information of how your data structures are set up. What is saved inside in the user defaults for key "users"?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I added the structure of "user" array on my post.

Comment: You have to forgive me, it's 5:53AM, but users[1] is a dictionary object, yes? If so I don't see an error in my TextEdit copy/paste. =]

Comment: Yes, users[1] should be a dictionary object. it has two keys which are   "label" and "users".

Comment: I guess I messed up something while editing. This error didn't happen before I post this question.

Comment: You got this error with the other solution as well. I think the problem lies with your saved data. How did you print the data structure? And when? Could be you have corruption in the user defaults.

Comment: I added NSLog(@"%@", users) right after this line. NSMutableArray *users = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"users"] mutableCopy];

Comment: It's weird but now I don't get this error."'-[__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]

Comment: But I have another problem now. When saveData method is called, it should rebuild my table view, but it doesn't. I was ok before.

Comment: In my code, I have added another user. But nowhere in the code do we tell the table to refresh. In your example, there is no mention of a table view. You need to call the view controller with the table view  and tell it that data has changed.

Comment: In my ListViewController.m, I have these methods.- (void)pushCreateBtn
{
    
    
    CreateModalViewController *createModalVIewController = [[CreateModalViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:createModalVIewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    createModalVIewController.target = self;
    createModalVIewController.action = @selector(refreshTableData);
    
}


- (void)refreshTableData
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: In my CreateModalViewController.m, I have saveData method which is on my post. And in this method, I have this line.     [self.target performSelector:self.action withObject:@"test.png"];

Answer (score 1):

The array `users` you are getting is not a mutable copy:

```
NSMutableArray *users = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"users"];
```

You're using `temporaryArray`, `temporary` and `testArray` for the same array? Typo? I think what you want is:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *users = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"users"] mutableCopy];

NSDictionary *myData = @{@"name":@"test", @"birthdate":@"1981-01-01", @"sex":@"male"};

NSMutableArray *usersNested = [users[1][@"users"] mutableCopy];
[usersNested addObject:myData];
[users replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:usersNested];

[userDefaults setObject:users forKey:@"users"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, temporary and testArray should be temporaryArray. I made a mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I'd like to add "myData" to users[1][@"users"], not "users".
So, I'm struggling with this.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just tried your code. But I got this error."'-[__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x942d7d0'"

Comment: I added the structure of "user"array on my post. Does it matter with this error?

Comment: You get that error when you call `[@"users"]` on an array instead of a dictionary. But based on your data model `users[1]` should be a dictionary not an array.